# Update table primary key and propagate changes to other tables

Tags: sql-server

I have Table A with Column A1Id as primary key, Column A1 and Column  A2.
I have Table B with Column A1Id as foreign key, Column B1, and Column B2. 
I have Table C with Column AI1d as foreign key, Column C1, and Column C2.

How can i update all the columns with a single command?
How can i propagate changes to all foreign keys if i update the primary key? 
I'm new to SQL is this a trivial task?

I'm currently having difficulty updating a single table because of the foreign key constraint.

Comment: Why would you want to update a primary key column?

Comment: No - it is a hugely complex task that is not suited to "new to SQL"

Comment: i have inherited a database and i don't know which columns are relevant, i need to generated minimal test data, but i need everything to match. when i add new data the primary keys are different.

Answer (score 1):

> How can i update all the columns with a single command?
>
> How can i propagate changes to all foreign keys if i update the primary key?
>
> is this a trivial task?

You can't do this with a single command, it is not a trivial task, it typically takes a script of sql commands with the changes repeated for each table; usually involving UPDATEs and new columns to "migrate" the old data to the new format. Changing primary keys is something that is done **very** infrequently, and is almost always considered a major change even when the specifics of that change are fairly minor.

The closest (physical) analogy I can think of offhand is trying to take something apart and replace all it's screws with bolts.

---

Edit: If you are just talking about changing the values, not the fields or data type of the values, used as primary keys; then R VISHAL's answer is pointing in the right direction. You'll need to drop all your current constraints and recreate them to cascade the updates. *You can also disable foreign key checks, change the values and then re-enable foreign key checks; but that is generally not recommended as re-enabling them does not recheck them, so if your updates put the data in an inconsistent state, it will not be corrected or even detected; and the setting is global, so any other activity going on will also be free to ignore their own fk constraints.*

... but you shouldn't typically be changing primary key values either. If the value changes, it probably isn't a good candidate for a foreign key; and if it is a synthetic value (like an auto-incremented id) then you should almost never be changing it (many newer users are tempted to try to "condense" them when holes appear, but it is seldom a good idea.)

Comment: Yup primary key values aren't to be tampered with once Inserted they are either to be forgotten or deleted but NEVER updated. If u were to update (like changing an phone number or email address) then u must use an actual programming language where u can compare and contrast values from your whole database to maintain consistency

Answer (score 1):

If, in your case, table B(A1id) and table C(A1id) both reference table A(A1id), then to propagate either update or delete operations to all foreign keys of tables B,C they should have the CASCADE constraint in them. In MySQL, for example, you could do this:

```
ALTER TABLE B 
ADD CONSTRAINT FKA 
   FOREIGN KEY B(A1id) 
   REFERENCES A(A1id) 
   ON UPDATE CASCADE 
   ON DELETE CASCADE
```

Notice the word cascade.  Is this what u want or am I missing something here? :/

Comment: How about the data for the other columns how can they get updated aswell?

Comment: The above code will update all your foreign keys to the value of your primary key. If u want some extra work to go in them after updating or deleting maybe to some different value or affect different unrelated tables all together then u have to look into TRIGGERS,PROCEDURES, FUNCTIONS here is an sample CREATE TRIGGER MYTRIGGER.                                                           AFTER UPDATE ON A.                                          //Table name.         FOR EACH ROW BEGIN /*Your code after updating table a*/ END;  in.mysql only. Have a look at the docs :)

Comment: Or best option use an actual programming language like java( just one of many for my example) and connect to your database via jdbc. Then in ur java code go nuts :D